# Как написать правило для .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache

Здравствуйте. Есть папка reports, в ней есть файлы report-(номер отчета).html как по запросу например domain.com/reports/report-10.html перенаправлять их на файлы /rewrite.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/reports/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/rewrite.php [R=301,L]
```

Попробуйте так

Comment: Не работает, просто открывает файл находящийся в папке /reports

Comment: Все равно открывает файл в папке

Comment: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/
тестировал тут, вроде работает.
может у вас закешировалось. Попробуйте в анонимном режиме